# Error in The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object

Tags: java, android, arrays, types

In the following code:

```
public class ColorTableDialog extends Dialog
  implements View.OnClickListener
{        
    public ColorTableDialog(Context paramContext)
      {
        super(paramContext);
        requestWindowFeature(1);
        Object localObject = new int[16];
      }

      ColorTableDialog(Context paramContext)
          {
            super(paramContext);
            requestWindowFeature(1);
            Object localObject = new int[16];
            localObject[0] = -1;
            localObject[1] = -4144960;
            localObject[2] = -8355712;
            localObject[3] = -16777216;
            localObject[4] = -65536;
            localObject[5] = -8388608;
            localObject[6] = -256;
            localObject[7] = -8355840;
            localObject[8] = -16711936;
            localObject[9] = -16744448;
            localObject[10] = -16711681;
            localObject[11] = -16744320;
            localObject[12] = -16776961;
            localObject[13] = -16777088;
            localObject[14] = -65281;
            localObject[15] = -8388480;
            this.mColors = ((I)localObject);
            setContentView(main);
            localObject = (ScrollView)findViewById(main);
    }
}
```

Here i got the error

> Error in The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object.

Actually, I lost my source code.  I decompiled this code, and got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is in this line:

```
 Object localObject = new int[16];
```

Here, you're declaring `localObject` to have static type `Object`.  Although it's really referring to an array of `int`s, the compiler only remembers that its type is `Object`.  Accordingly, when you then say

```
localObject[0] = -1;
```

etc., the compiler only remembers that `localObject` is an `Object`, not an `int[]`.  That is, it doesn't know that it's not referring to something like a `String` or `HashSet<Integer>`, in which case applying the braces is not allowed.

To fix this, change the type of `localObject` to be `int[]`, as in

```
int[] localObject = new int[16];
```

That way, the compiler remembers that it's an array of `int`s, and all will work out just great.

More generally, unless you have a good reason not to, it's usually a good idea to give types to your variables that are as specific as possible.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you can use:
 ((int[])localObject)[0]=-1
to cast the localObject which is Objcet type to the int[] type.

Since the int[] type(not the int type) is one of the subclasses of Object type, and you have given an array which is int[] type to localObject, so the expression a=(int[])localObject will retrive the int[] type from localObject which is Object type, and by using a[0] you can get the element you want from the array a.

Hope this answer is helpful!

Comment: Check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.